# How to run python from the terminal if I installed it using Visual Studio?

Tags: python

I have installed python using Visual Studio, but I can't use python from the command prompt. I also want to run python from the command prompt, but it is only accessible from Visual Studio. I have tried adding the path of the directory in which Visual Studio has installed python to the user environment variables, but typing python in the command prompt opens up Windows Store.
Please somebody help me with this. Is there any way around or do I have to install python separately too.

Comment: How about uninstalling from VS, then installing like normal? (through the store or the official binaries from Python website)

Comment: In your terminal while in the root directory of the C drive try the command `dir /b/s python.exe` and edit tell me what yhe output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for replying. I figured out the answer myself, and thought to answer it for anyone in the future who comes across the same issue.

I went into settings->Apps

Find the python installation and click on it, select modify.

Then click on "modify installation" when the python installation repair window opens, then again click on "modify", make sure to select "Add python to path", and also py launcher option also.

That fixed the problem for me.

Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

go to [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and download the latest version of python (You can download it from the windows store too). Then open a new terminal and write `python --version`.

```
NOTE: Don`t forget the open a new terminal.
```

Answer (score 0):

step1 : install the python from [python.org](https://www.python.org) (dont forget to check the PATH installation radio button)

step2: check the python from CMD with command :

> python --version

step3: go the project directory and run :

> python your_project_file_name.py